# Recreating Apache .htaccess in Nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been tasked to create some previously working Apache rewrites to work on Nginx. There's a whole bunch of rules that we were instructed to create by the SEO consultants that are working fine on Apache. They are quite specific to particular products and categories.

Here's an example of a rewrite that works on Apache

`RewriteRule ^category/fridge-and-frozen/cheese$ category/fridge-and-frozen/organic-cheese? [L,R=301]`

`RewriteRule ^product/Sprouted-Ezekiel-4:9-Brea-Pure-Life-11kg$ product/Sprouted-Ezekiel-Bread-Pure-Life-11kg? [L,R=301]`

For one reason or other the site is moving from Apache to Nginx. And I have been trying to create the same rules in Nginx. And alas they are not working. I'm a coder, not a web server administrator, but small company etc.

I have tried to create various versions of these rewrite rules to work on Nginx but to no avail. Here is an example of one attempt:

`rewrite ^category/fridge-and-frozen/cheese$ category/fridge-and-frozen/organic-cheese permanent;`

Wonder if someone could give me advice on how to get this redirect to work.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> rewrite ^category/fridge-and-frozen/cheese$ category/fridge-and-frozen/organic-cheese permanent;
> ```

The URL-path matched by the `rewrite` directive is root-relative and starts with a slash. Likewise, I believe the target URL should also start with slash. For example:

```
rewrite ^/category/fridge-and-frozen/cheese$ /category/fridge-and-frozen/organic-cheese permanent;
```

However, it also depends where you are putting this directive in your config.

If you previously had any erroneous 301/permanent redirects then these will have also been cached by the browser.

Comment: Makes sense come to think of it. Thanks for that. All working.